# How to remove Vertical and Horizontal scroll bar from DataGridView in C sharp?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have added rows and columns dynamically in DataGridView, but here I want to remove Vertical and Horizontal scroll bar and also I want to display individual [row][columnn] value when I click on particular cell. I go through from [here:](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/grid/virtual-grid)

but I did not cleared my concept.

How to make it possible.

**Below is part of my code:**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        update();
    }
    public void update()
    {
        //Add Columns.
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "NSE";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "BSE";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "MCX";
        //Add Rows
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("1");
        row.Add("2");
        row.Add("3");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());

        //2nd Row
        row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("4");
        row.Add("5");
        row.Add("6");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());

        //3rd Row
        row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("7");
        row.Add("8");
        row.Add("9");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        //4th Row
        row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("10");
        row.Add("11");
        row.Add("12");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        //5th Row
        row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("13");
        row.Add("14");
        row.Add("15");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
    }
}}
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;` should do the trick. It's not clear what *"... display individual [row][columnn] value"* means. Try adding a `dataGridView1.CellClick` event handler and see what you can make of it.

Comment: @Filburt  Thank you,It's working. next I want to display the row index value and column index value when I click on any single cell.
How to do?

Comment: `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` is an argument to the `.CellClick` event handler and come with `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this......................**

```
    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 400px; height: auto; max-width: 1000px; width: auto;">
 <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CellPadding="5" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="10">                            <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="2%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<HeaderTemplate> Sl No. 
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblSRNO" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblByerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StyleId")%>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>                            
     </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Comment: The link and code rather suggest WinForms than ASP.NET. Also you should explain how this answers the OPs question.